# Accessing mac's sensor data

Tags: c++, python, macos

Is there a way to get ambient light sensors data on mac using Python and/or C++? Googled it but didn't find much information.Most of the info there is related to Objective-C

Comment: Is the data available via IPMI?

Answer (score 2):

this looks to be non-trivial ... you will probably need to use C/C++ to make a swig component

Here is a project that reads the sudden movement sensor data .... take a look at it

http://code.google.com/p/pyapplesms/source/browse/trunk/applesms.c